# Accessing the error object inside of exceptionhandler method

Tags: java, error-handling, exception, exceptionhandler

Is there any way to get inside to the exception object when using annotation @ExceptionHandler?

this is my code:

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataInputException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleException(){
         return ResponseEntity
                    .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .body("Entity contains null or forbidden values");
    }
```

I'd like to have returned message to contain customized info about perticular fields. (That's why I need error object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in the exception

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataInputException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleException(DataInputException exception) {
```